# Finitely generated nilpotent groups with hyperbolic automorphisms

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, nilpotent-groups, outer-automorphisms

$\DeclareMathOperator\Out{Out}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$
Let $G$ be a finitely generated nilpotent group.

We call an automorphism of $G$ **hyperbolic** if the induced automorphism of the free part of the abelianization $G/[G,G]$ is hyperbolic (no eigenvalue on the unit circle).

I want to know conditions for $\Out(G)$ to contain a hyperbolic element.

**Examples/Remarks:**

1. Finitely generated abelian groups with non-trivial free parts have this property, so I am only interested in non-abelian cases.
2. On the other hand, there exist examples of $G$ where $\Out(G)$ is unipotent, so not every $G$ works.
3. The discrete 3D Heisenberg group has this property since in that case $\Out(G)\cong \GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$; like in the abelian case.
4. More generally, Lior Silberman has explained to me why both the $(2n+1)$ Heisenberg groups $H_n$ (over $\mathbb{Z}$), and also free nilpotent groups $F_s$ of step size $s$ have this property.

In short, a set generates a nilpotent group if and only if its image generates the abelianization (see for example [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16777/generation-in-a-group-versus-generation-in-its-abelianization)). Consequently, the automorphism group of a free nilpotent group on $r$ generators surjects onto $\GL(r, \mathbb{Z})$ and likewise the automorphism group of $H_n$ surjects onto $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{Z})$.  These surjective maps imply hyperbolic elements exist in $\Out(G)$.

> What other examples of $G$ are there with this property?

Another colleague of mine pointed out to me that more exotic examples could arise from nil-manifolds who admit Anosov automorphisms. I am certainly interested in concrete examples along these lines, but any new examples would interest me.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of the rational Malcev completion, the criterion only depends on $\mathfrak{g}$ (i.e., is a commensurability invariant of the given discrete group), and more precisely only depends on a maximal $\mathbf{Q}$-anisotropic torus $T$ of $\mathrm{Aut}\mathfrak{g}$, namely the condition is satisfied iff $T$ has no fixed line on the abelianization of $\mathfrak{g}$. Given this, one should be able to make a systematic check up to Hirsch rank 6.

Comment: (To answer a deleted comment) There are f.g. nilpotent elements in arbitrary Hirsch rank $\ge 7$ in which all automorphisms are "virtually unipotent", hence no hyperbolic one. And actually, lattices in filiform groups in dimension $\ge 4$ (i.e., $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^{r-1}$ for $r\ge 3$, with action by a unipotent matrix with a single Jordan block) have no hyperbolic automorphism either, since in this case the maximal torus in Aut(g) is split.

Comment: Unipotent radicals of parabolic subgroups of reductive groups have actions by the corresponding Levi factors, whose $\mathbb{Z}$-points will often include hyperbolic elements.

Comment: A side remark: Anosov means there an automorphism acting hyperbolically on $g$; here one asks it to act hyperbolically on $g/[g,g]$, which is weaker (for instance it allows the Heisenberg group, which is not Anosov).